# Automate 3 different click events on a timer using javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to automate the click events defined below on a timer. Say every 5-6 seconds or so. So the page starts out on 'longevity' and a user click is simulated using javascript on a loop. The loop should stop running once a user has manually clicked on a tab as well. Any ideas ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function(){
         $("#integrity").click(function(){
          $('#home_image').removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass('bg1');
         });
      });

      $("document").ready(function(){
         $("#quality").click(function(){
          $('#home_image').removeClass('bg1 , bg3').addClass('bg2');
         });
      });

      $("document").ready(function(){
         $("#longevity").click(function(){
          $('#home_image').removeClass('bg1 , bg2').addClass('bg3');
         });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Do they need to be "clicked" in succession? One after the next every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) instead of looping. Encapsulate the code for each tab in its own function. Set the intervals for each of those using setTimeout so that you are cycling between the tabs. save the return values from setInterval, so that you can use them to clear the intervals when the user clicks on a tab.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function integrity(){
       $('#home_image').removeClass('bg2 , bg3').addClass('bg1');
    }


    function quality(){
       $('#home_image').removeClass('bg1 , bg3').addClass('bg2');
    }

    function longevity(){
       $('#home_image').removeClass('bg1 , bg2').addClass('bg3');
    }

    var integrityInterval;
    setTimeout(function(){integrityInterval = setInterval(integrity,15000)},5000);

    var qualityInterval;
    setTimeout(function(){qualityInterval = setInterval(quality,15000)},5000);

    var longevityInterval;
    setTimeout(function(){longevityInterval = setInterval(longevity,15000)},5000);

    $('#integrity').click(function(){
      clearInterval(integrityInterval);
      interval();
    });

    $('#quality').click(function(){
      clearInterval(qualityInterval);
      quality();
    });

    $('#longevity').click(function(){
          clearInterval(longevityInterval);
          longevity();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the entire example as it was wrong. [test](http://jsfiddle.net/rthgF/1/)

HTML:

```
<button id="integrity" class="buttonColor">integrity</button>
<button id="quality" class="buttonColor">quality</button>
<button id="longevity" class="buttonColor">longevity</button>

<div id="home_image">background-color</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg1{
   background-color:#e62083;
}
.bg2{
   background-color:#003caf;
}
.bg3{
   background-color:#684a00;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

  var 
      home_image = $('#home_image'), 
      timeout,
      addBetween = (function(aValues, firth){

          var 
              ini = 0,
              end = aValues.length -1;
              actual = (firth) ? (firth - 1) : (ini - 1);

          return {
              next: function(){
                  actual++;
                  if (actual > end)
                     actual = ini;
                  return aValues[actual];
              }
          };
      })(["integrity", "quality", "longevity"], 3),
      colorBackGround = function(isTrigger) {

        var 
           self = this;

        isTrigger = isTrigger || false;

        if (!isTrigger)
           clearTimeout(timeout);

        $(home_image)
            .removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3')
            .addClass(function(index, class) {   // jQuery 1.4

                var 
                    id = (isTrigger) ? addBetween.next() : $(self)[0].id,
                    newClass = "";

                switch(id) {
                  case "integrity":
                     newClass = "bg1"; break;
                  case "quality":
                     newClass = "bg2"; break;
                  case "longevity":
                     newClass = "bg3"; break;
                }

                $("#test").html(id + " " + newClass + " " + class);
                return newClass;
            });

        if (isTrigger)
            timeout = setTimeout(function() { colorBackGround.call({}, true); }, 1000);

      };

  $(".buttonColor").bind("click", function(ev) {

    colorBackGround.call(this, false);

  });

  colorBackGround.call({}, true);


});
```

Comment: Couldnt get this working in my test scenario either. not really sure where to go on this one....

Comment: could you put the html of the buttons to perform the test?